# Domain events in the unit of work pattern

Tags: c#, design-patterns, event-handling

I've used the unit of work pattern to wrap my business logic. (Note that the application has three states: Logedout, LogedIn, Loaded)

```
public class LogoutUnitOfWork
{
    public void Execute()
    {
        new UnloadUnitOfWork().Execute(false);

        // navigate to the "logout view"

        // do some business related work

        // navigate to the "login view" (Logedout state)
    }
}

public class UnloadUnitOfWork
{
    public void Execute(bool navigate = true)
    {
        // navigate to the "unloading view"

        // do some business related work
        _legacyService.Unload();

        if(navigate)
        {
            // => navigate to the "logedin view" (LogedIn state)
        }
    }
}

// not relevant for now
public class LoadUnitOfWork {}
public class LoginUnitOfWork {}
```

Until now non of the work units was directly listening to an event. I have place where I listen to domain events and execute an unit of work if nessesary.

```
public void ConfigureApplicationEvents()
{
    _eventAggregator.GetEvent<TimeoutEvent>().Subscribe(() =>
    {
        new UnloadUnitOfWork().Execute();
    }

    ...
}
```

Or I execute this unit of works from the UI (When a button was clicked).

---

But I have a legacy dependency which also publishes events. Now I have to listen to this events and then navigate to the view which represents the new state. The problem is that I do not know where the event came from.

```
_legacyService.Unloading += (sender, args) =>
{
    // navigate to the "unloading view"
};
_legacyService.Unloaded += (sender, args) =>
{
    // where should I navigate to? 
    // I need to know if the event came from the LogoutUnitOfWork, UnloadUnitOfWork or from the legacy dependency directly.
};
```

At the moment I solve this like the following:

```
var setShouldNavigateQueue = new Queue<Action>();
var shouldNavigate = true;

_legacyService.Unloading += (sender, args) =>
{
    // navigate to the "unloading view"
};
_legacyService.Unloaded += (sender, args) =>
{
    // do some buisiness related work

    if (shouldNavigate)
    {
        // => navigate to the "logedin view" (LogedIn state)
    }

    // as the legacy service reports back after the unit of work events
    // we execute the actions that have been queued 
    // (should be only one which sets `shouldNavigate` to the default value)
    while (setShouldNavigateQueue.Any())
    {
        setShouldNavigateQueue.Dequeue().Invoke();
    }
};

// this events come from the unit of work
_eventAggregator.GetEvent<UnloadingEvent>().Subscribe(navigateToTarget =>
{
    // the unit of work knows if after the unloading a navigation should occure
    // this navigation wonn't happen for example when the `LogoutUnitOfWork` was
    // executed because it will navigate by itself
    shouldNavigate = navigateToTarget;
});
_eventAggregator.GetEvent<UnloadedEvent>().Subscribe(() =>
{
    // the unit of work reports first that the unloading is done
    // push the action which sets the `shouldNavigate` to the default value into the queue
    setShouldNavigateQueue.Enqueue(() => shouldNavigate = true);
});

public class LogoutUnitOfWork
{
    public void Execute()
    {
        new UnloadUnitOfWork().Execute(false);

        // navigate to the "logout in progress view"

        // do some business related work

        // navigate to the "login view" (Logedout state)
    }
}

public class UnloadUnitOfWork
{
    public void Execute(bool navigate = true)
    {
        _eventAggregator.GetEvent<UnloadingEvent>().Publish(navigate);

        // navigate to the "unloading in progress view"

        // do some business related work
        _legacyService.Unload();            

        _eventAggregator.GetEvent<UnloadedEvent>().Publish();
    }
}
```

But this is to hard to read and could be missleading to others.

- How could I change my code to make it simpler?
- Should I wait and also listen for this legacy events in my unit of work?
  (I would find this strange as the unit of work then could start by itself which is a concept not found yet in my app)

PS: If I let out any informations you need or if I wrote a little confusing please let me know that I can improve this post and my writing style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by checking the current active view and only do the navigate when the "unloading view" is active. Because the `UnloadUnitOfWork` calls the `CleanUp` method (which is doing the navigation) before the event of the legacy service I can decide there where I need to navigate to.

```
public class LogoutUnitOfWork
{
    public void Execute()
    {
        new UnloadUnitOfWork().Execute(false);

        // navigate to the "logout view"

        // do some business related work

        // navigate to the "login view" (Logedout state)
    }
}

public class UnloadUnitOfWork
{
    public void Execute(bool navigate = true)
    {
        // navigate to the "unloading view"

        // do some business related work
        _legacyService.Unload();

        CleanUp(navigate)
    }

    public void CleanUp(bool navigate)
    {
        // this method is called twice
        // in case the unloading happened through an
        // event from the legacy service it will only be called once
        if(!IsUnloadingViewActive())
            return;

        // do some buisiness related work

        if(navigate)
        {
            // => navigate to the "logedin view" (LogedIn state)
        }
    }
}

_legacyService.Unloading += (sender, args) =>
{
    // navigate to the "unloading view" if not yet active
};
_legacyService.Unloaded += (sender, args) =>
{
    new UnloadUnitOfWork().CleanUp(true);
};
```

Maybe I'm going to introduce a state management to remove the depencency on the views.

---

I've now added a state management. The unit of works won't be called from the events or ui anymore. They will only be called by the states. Furthermore I've added an so called `IApplicationTransitionState` which will persist details about why and how the state change was called.

View specific code is implemented in this `IApplicationTransitionState`'s. Business specific code will still be implemented in the `UnitOfWork`'s.

```
public class StateContext : IApplicationState
{
    private IApplicationState _currentState;
    private IApplicationTransitionState _transitionState;

    public bool IsInTransition => _transitionState?.HasEnded ?? false;

    public static StateContext Instance { get; } = new StateContext();

    private StateContext() { }

    public void Login() => TransiteState(() => _currentState.Login());
    public void Logout() => TransiteState(() => _currentState.Logout());
    public void Load() => TransiteState(() => _currentState.Load());
    public void Unload() => TransiteState(() => _currentState.Unload());

    public bool CanLogin() => _currentState.CanLogin();
    public bool CanLogout() => _currentState.CanLogout();
    public bool CanLoad() => _currentState.CanLoad();
    public bool CanUnload() => _currentState.CanUnload();

    public void EndTransition()
    {
        _transitionState.EndTransition();
    }

    private void ThrowIfInTransition()
    {
        if(!_transitionState.HasEnded)
            throw new Exception();
    }

    private void HandleTransitionState(Action transitAction)
    {
        ThrowIfInTransition();
        _transitionState = transitAction.Invoke();
        Task.Run(transitionState.StartTransition);
    }
}

public interface IApplicationState
{
    IApplicationTransitionState Login();
    IApplicationTransitionState Logout();
    IApplicationTransitionState Load();
    IApplicationTransitionState Unload();

    bool CanLogin();
    bool CanLogout();
    bool CanLoad();
    bool CanUnload();
}

public interface IApplicationTransitionState
{
    bool HasEnded { get; set; }

    void StartTransition();
    void EndTransition();
}
```

The implementation is the following. I've left out the `LoginTransitionState` and `LoadingTransitionState`.

```
public enum UnloadReason
{
    LoginOut,
    Unloading,
    Event
}
public enum LoginReason
{
    Login,
    Loading
}

public class StartedState : IApplicationState
{
    public IApplicationTransitionState Load()
        => new LoginTransitionState { Reason = LoginReason.Load };

    public IApplicationTransitionState Login()
        => new LoginTransitionState  { Reason = LoginReason.Login };

    public IApplicationTransitionState Logout()
        => throw new Exception();

    public IApplicationTransitionState Unload()
        => throw new Exception();

    public bool CanUnload() => false;
    public bool CanLogout() => false;
    public bool CanLoad() => true;
    public bool CanLogin() => true;
}

public class LogedInState : IApplicationState 
{
    public IApplicationTransitionState Load()
        => new LoadingTransitionState();

    public IApplicationTransitionState Logout()
        => new LogoutTransitionState();

    public IApplicationTransitionState Unload()
        => throw new Exception();

    public IApplicationTransitionState Login()
        => throw new Exception();

    public bool CanLogin() => false;
    public bool CanUnload() => false;
    public bool CanLoad() => true;
    public bool CanLogout() => true;
}

public class LoadedState : IApplicationState
{
    public IApplicationTransitionState Logout()
        => new UnloadingTransitionState { Reason = UnloadReason.LoginOut };

    public IApplicationTransitionState Unload()
        => new UnloadingTransitionState { Reason = UnloadReason.Unloading }

    public IApplicationTransitionState Login()
        => throw new Exception();

    public IApplicationTransitionState Load()
        => throw new Exception();

    public bool CanLogin() => false;
    public bool CanLoad() => false;
    public bool CanLogout() => true;
    public bool CanUnload() => true;
}


public class LoginTransitionState : IApplicationTransitionState { }
public class LoadingTransitionState : IApplicationTransitionState { }
public class LogoutTransitionState : IApplicationTransitionState
{
    public bool HasEnded { get; set; }

    public void StartTransition()
    {
        // navigate to the "login out view"

        new LogoutUnitOfWork().Execute();
    }

    public void EndTransition()
    {       
        HasEnded = true;

        // navigate to the "login view"
    }
}
public class UnloadingTransitionState : IApplicationTransitionState
{
    public bool HasEnded { get; set; }
    public UnloadReason Reason { get; set; }

    public void StartTransition()
    {
        // navigate to the "unloading view"

        new UnloadUnitOfWork().Execute();
    }

    public void EndTransition()
    {       
        HasEnded = true;

        if(Reason != UnloadReason.LoginOut)
        {
            // navigate to the "load view"
        }
        else 
        {
            StateContext.Instance.Logout();
        }
    }
}

public class LogoutUnitOfWork
{
    public void Execute()
    {
        if(StateContext.Instance.CanUnload())
            StateContext.Instance.Unload();

        // logout
    }
}

public class UnloadUnitOfWork
{
    public void Execute()
    {
        _legacyService.Unload();
    }
}

_legacyService.Unloading += (sender, args) => 
{
    if(StateContext.Instance.CanUnload())
        StateContext.Instance.Unload();
};
_legacyService.Unloaded += (sender, args) =>
{
    if(StateContext.Instance.IsInTransition)
        StateContext.Instance.EndTransition();      
};
```

The `EndTransition` method will either be called from outside of the sate management (e.g. from an legacy service event). Or from within when not external depencency exists.